# How to force users to crop an image in Filestack V3

Tags: filepicker.io

In filestack v2 I was able to force users to crop an image after they uploaded it using the 'cropForce' attribute like this:

```
filepicker.pick(
    {
    mimetype: 'image/*',
    cropForce: true,
    cropRatio: 8/2.5,
    conversions: ['crop'],
    services: ['CONVERT','COMPUTER','INSTAGRAM','URL','FACEBOOK','GOOGLE_DRIVE','IMAGE_SEARCH']
    }, function(response){

    }
);
```

However in filestack V3 there is no more option to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is most definitely a bit late in the game for you. I believe the features you required were released in July 2017.

For other people trying to figure this out, the V3 equivalent to what you're trying to achieve:

```
pickerOptions = {
  accept: 'image/*',
  transformations: {
    crop: {
      aspectRatio: 8/2.5,
      force: true
    }
  },
  fromSources: ['local_file_system', 'instagram', 'url', 'facebook', 'googledrive', 'imagesearch']
};
```

For reference to forcing cropping see:

https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickeroptions.html#transformations &
https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickertransformationoptions.html
& https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickercropoptions.html

Answer (score 2):

Force crop is a feature that is presently in the development pipeline for V3 and should be available for users in the near future.

Answer (score -1):

Force Crop is available by setting

```
transformations: { crop: true }
```

in the .pick() function.

Comment: Hey @Flutterby_Dev, this doesn't seem to force cropping, rather it allows the user to use the transform in the picker widget. Ref: https://filestack.github.io/filestack-js/interfaces/pickeroptions.html#transformations